# invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct ether_arp'

Tags: android, android-ndk

i'm trying to compile batctl-2012.0.0 from open-mesh.org, with android-ndk, but, in progress, tcpdump.c give invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct ether_arp'. Please tell me where or how to solve it. thank you very much

```
static void dump_arp(unsigned char *packet_buff, ssize_t buff_len, int time_printed)
{
struct ether_arp *arphdr;

LEN_CHECK((size_t)buff_len, (long)sizeof(struct ether_arp), "ARP");

if (!time_printed)
    print_time();

arphdr = (struct ether_arp *)packet_buff;

switch (ntohs(arphdr->arp_op)) {
case ARPOP_REQUEST:
    printf("ARP, Request who-has %s", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)&arphdr->arp_tpa));
    printf(" tell %s (%s), length %zd\n", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)&arphdr->arp_spa),
        ether_ntoa_long((struct ether_addr *)&arphdr->arp_sha), buff_len);
    break;
case ARPOP_REPLY:
    printf("ARP, Reply %s is-at %s, length %zd\n", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)&arphdr->arp_spa),
        ether_ntoa_long((struct ether_addr *)&arphdr->arp_sha), buff_len);
    break;
default:
    printf("ARP, unknown op code: %i\n", ntohs(arphdr->arp_op));
    break;
}
}
```

and this in terminal

```
/home/renanto/workspace/androidbatctl/jni/tcpdump.c: In function 'dump_arp':
/home/renanto/workspace/androidbatctl/jni/tcpdump.c:96: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct ether_arp' 
/home/renanto/workspace/androidbatctl/jni/tcpdump.c:96: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct ether_arp'
```

Answer (score 1):

"Incomplete type" means the compiler can't see the definition of the structure. You can't use `sizeof` or access any fields on an incomplete type.

To make this function work, you need to `#include` the header file which has the definition of `struct ether_arp`. Since it's a Linux struct, not an Android-specific one, you should find it in the include path within the NDK.

```
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
```

Comment: I have the same issue, and now I'm looking where the either_arp resides in Android headers. http://osxr.org/android/ident?_i=ether_arp seems to be a good tool for such purpose

Comment: According to my searching, struct ether_arp is not defined in Android source code at all...

Comment: @Mixaz That's because it's not an Android struct, but a Linux one (a POSIX one, to be precise). I've updated my answer with more info.

Comment: #include <netinet/if_ether.h> doesn't help, I tried that before posting. I believe http://osxr.org/android/ident?_i=ether_arp looks for ether_arp references in whole android tree, including linux kernel. For me, it looks like ether_arp is not used in android code at all, if you look at the link you'll see that netinet/if_ether.h has its definition only under #ifdef __USE_BSD, which is not the case for Android IMHO. Only /external/bluetooth/hcidump/parser/tcpip.c (in Android source code) seems to use it, and it is commented out there.

Comment: I heard that ARP packet is absent in IPv6, replaced with iCMPv6 features - may be because of that?